# Randomized Parallel Algorithm for Maximal Independent Set

Tags: reference-request, randomized-algorithms, dc.parallel-comp, derandomization

There are a couple of randomized parallel algorithms for the maximal independent set problem, e.g. [A Simple Parallel Algorithm for the Maximal Independent Set Problem](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0215074), [A fast and simple randomized parallel algorithm for the maximal independent set problem](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0196677486900192).

These algorithms were the (or one of the) first examples where $k$-wise independent events/random variables are used to derandomize parallel algorithms. One algorithm (which is described [here](http://dcg.ethz.ch/lectures/podc_allstars/lecture/chapter7.pdf) in the chapter "Fast MIS v2") works as follows:

```
The algorithm operates in synchronous rounds, grouped into phases.
A single phase is as follows:
1) Each node v chooses a random value r(v) from [0,1] and sends it to its
neighbors.
2) If r(v) < r(w) for all neighbors w in N(v), node v enters the MIS and
informs its neighbors.
3) If v or a neighbor of v entered the MIS, v terminates (v and all edges
adjacent to v are removed from the graph), otherwise v enters the next phase.
```

**My question:** Is it known that this algorithm also works if the random values are $k$-wise or even pairwise independent?

I didn't find anything in the literature but maybe I just miss something.